# HTML/PHP Form - Not allowing me to make a space in a textbox input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a space in the textboxes after you click [UPLOAD YOUR OWN PHOTO] on http://www.maltarestaurantreviews.com/

I double checked the code and found nothing that is stopping me from writing a SPACE in my text.

Comment: Please show some code here. And describe more clearly what goes wrong - does the space get swallowed? Where?

Comment: Did you get your URL wrong or is this just spam to increase clicks to this website?

Comment: Am i the only one who cannot find this [UPLOAD YOUR OWN PHOTO] button?

Comment: @Charlie: I've found it. `People's Gallery` -> `[…upload your own photo…]`

Comment: -1 because this is a very poorly written question with a link that doesn't even lead to a page that relates to the question. Please edit and I'll undo the -1.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you have a space Keydown event attached to your spacebar on the entire page.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

everytime you hit spacebar.

it is reside in this script: `/js/jquery.galleriffic.js`

```
    // Setup Keyboard Navigation
            if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation) {
                $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
                    switch(key) {
                    /* right here =>    case 32: // space
                            gallery.next();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            break; */
//continue code...
```

Are you using the gallery's space keydown functions if not just remove it else make sure the form isn't conflicting w/ the space keydown.  However, it might cause some side effects that you might not want.  So, it's really specific to what you want to do with the entire site.

Comment: That's a really strange behaviour, as **spaces in filenames are allowed**. :/

Comment: the keydown event is attachd to entire document $(document)

Comment: Hello Thanks for answering but I still cans figure it out I removeed the complete key event pressing function and it sill does it :S

Comment: you have alot of plugins on the page, and i am not sure how you want the entire page to function, but to remove space from the keydown then remove case 32: // space
                            gallery.next();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            break;

Comment: i am trying to disable them and enable them one by one to see where the problem is

Comment: So the problem is not the plugins... its the js/jquery.galleriffic.js because when i disable it then the textbox spaces work and I also removeed the case 32...

Comment: GOT IT WORKING! Thanks , I made a comment on case 32 ,before I delete the whole function

Comment: Yes, that's what i was pointing out on the answer.  @Wil i would recommand accepting more answers by clicking on the check aka accept mark because the more you accept answers the more people are willing to help you with your questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the only plugin with the key event handler is galleriffic, then simply uncommenting the following lines

/*case 32: // space
gallery.next();
e.preventDefault();
break;*/

would solve your problem.

I've had that issue before. That was exactly how i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
This works for me:
    // Setup Keyboard Navigation

    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation) {
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {

            var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // hack
            //disable navigation on an input editable element
            if (target && target.type) return true;         

            var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
            switch(key) {
                case 32: // space
                        gallery.next();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        break;
                case 33: // Page Up
                    gallery.previousPage();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 34: // Page Down
                    gallery.nextPage();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 35: // End
                    gallery.gotoIndex(gallery.data.length-1);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 36: // Home
                    gallery.gotoIndex(0);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 37: // left arrow
                    gallery.previous();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case 39: // right arrow
                    gallery.next();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```